# Entity Framework 4 Design Question

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

I need a little advice on how to best solve this issue please.

I have Customer, CustomerLocations, SalesOrder, and Invoice entities.

The customer needs to be able to have multiple billing/shipping address, per customer and per location, sort of like an address book. Simple!!

The SalesOrder and Invoice objects need to be able to store these addresses when created. Again, simple!!

Here is the deal though, I don't want to use a foreign key on the salesorder or invoice items, but the actual fields of the address (Line1, Line2, City, State....).

What would be the best way to solve this?

## Update

How about this?[image]

## Or

[image]

and then you could access it like this:

```
Partial Public Class Customer

Public ReadOnly Property DefaultBillingAddress As Address
    Get
        Return Locations.First(Function(x) x.IsDefault).BillingAddresses.First(Function(x) x.IsDefault)
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property DefaultShippingAddress As Address
    Get
        Return Locations.First(Function(x) x.IsDefault).ShippingAddresses.First(Function(x) x.IsDefault)
    End Get
End Property
```

End Class

Comment: make the fields in the address table unique key, then you can ref them as FK.  I'm working on business ware too - why do you have this requirement, i'm just curious?

Comment: @Gabriel - The customers need to be able to keep a collection of addresses to have orders shipped to different locations. What I am having a hard time understanding, is this: There needs to be two relationships between the address to customer, one for billing and another for shipping. How do you accomplish this? Like in the realtionship it would be cool if you could say "WHERE AddressType=1 (Billing)".

Comment: @Sam Striano: So why don't you add AddressType field to Addresses?

Comment: @LukLed - So let's look at this from an object viewpoint. The CustomerLocation object needs a collection of both shipping and billing addresses in theory. Unless I am mistaken, I can not hang a collection of Addresses (Address Entity) for both Shipping and Billing off of the CustomerLocation entity and then have the entity be able to tell the difference based on an AddressType field. Or can it?

Comment: @Sam Striano: What do you mean by "entity be able to tell the difference"? You can tell the difference by checking AddressType field:)

Comment: @LukLed - So are you saying have a 1-Many relationship between the CustomerLocation and the Address. Then hang a property off the CustomerLocation like BillingAddresses: `Public Readonly Property BillingAddresses AS IEnumerable(Of Address) Return Addresses.Where(Function(x) x.AddressType=1)`

Comment: @Sam Striano: Yes, that will be the easiest solution. I know that diagrams look better with ShippingAddress and BillingAddress, but I think that is too much.

Comment: @LukLed - I tried that, and it will work awesome... Brain was not working, maybe because I have been banging it on the desk trying to figure this one out. Thanks a lot!! ~ Sam

Comment: Generally, I'd say stay away from the concept of an "addresstype". After all, an address is an address, it's a street/city/state/zip whatever. It's how its +connected+ to the customer that determines whether it's a shipping or billing address. One way to look at it is, if I was JUST looking at an address, would it make any difference whether I knew it was a shipping or billing address? Probably not.